# Netgear WNR2000 as repeater for Cisco/Linksys E3000

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, repeater

Can I use a Netgear WNR2000 as a repeater for a Cisco/Linksys E3000?

My setup is::

> Time Warner cable Internet > Motorola DOCSIS wireless modem > Linksys E3000 router

This is upstairs.

Downstairs I have a Logitech Revue and an Acer Revo. I want both of these to connect via Ethernet to a Netgear WNR2000 so that they get their Internet over Ethernet and also have a fast connection between them for streaming video. Streaming HD content over the wireless is just not fast enough.

Is it possible to set up the WNR2000 as a repeater? (I'm not sure if that's even the correct term.) I want the WNR to pick up the Internet wirelessly and dole it out over Ethernet to the Revue and the Revo. I also want to share media from the Revo to the Revue over SMB over Ethernet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible..  The WNR2000 out of the box is not capable of doing what you want in the way that you want to do it.  It cannot receive one wireless connection and then pass that connection on via wireless or Ethernet.  The firmware as stands does not allow for the wireless component of the router to be set to receive a connection (like a wireless NIC in a computer can).

As I touched on, a wireless repeater requires two things to be able to function in this capacity.  It needs two discrete wireless components, and it requires software/firmware that allows you to set one of the wireless components to connect to a network source, while the second wireless component would then rebroadcast it.  Standard routers are neither designed to function in this capacity, nor are they designed to be modified to operate in this capacity.  Now, the WNR2000 v2 can be set to be a wireless repeater, if you replace the firmware with something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index).  [This thread here](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?p=521479&sid=0626729133a53eb038b9eb86347180fc) at the DD-WRT forums describes the method (in general by pointing to the DD-WRT instructions for accessing [Repeater Bridge Mode](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) in their firmware) and some of the issues they have come across.  I am not detailing all of the steps you would follow, because at this point you would be far better off moving to the DD-WRT site to bone up on everything you need to know to be able to replace your firmware, and the dangers involved therein.

In short, it can be done, but you've got some work ahead of you.  Providing, of course, the exact model and version of that Netgear Router is compatible with the proper version of DD-WRT for what you want to do.